# An individual “surging"

Tags: word-usage

I know that you can say that “a crowd surged forward.” However, can you say that “I surged forward”? Can the verb “surge” be used in reference to a single person?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ***[surge](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/surge_1?q=surge%20)*** can be used to refer to a single person to indicate a fast movement forward:

> - [intransitive] + adv./prep. to move quickly and with force in a particular direction:
>
>   - *The gates opened and the crowd surged forward.*
>   - *Flood waters surged into their homes.*
>   - ***He surged past the other runners on the last lap.***

Oxford Learners' Dictionary

Usage example from [Nebula Award Showcase](https://books.google.it/books?id=7zsrAQAAIAAJ&q=%22i%20surged%20forward%22&dq=%22i%20surged%20forward%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV_OHi9PTOAhVEIMAKHYPhAX0Q6AEIITAA):.

> - ...was descending now in maddeningly slow motion, but as soon as I was down, Cassandra still clinging hard to me, ***I surged forward a couple of paces then leapt up again.***  This time, there was nothing but unrelenting bulkhead overhead, and ...

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20surged%20forward&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20surged%20forward%3B%2Cc0): *I surged forward*

Comment: Absolutely correct. I plead caffiene deficiency.